# Get first item of QuerySet in template

Tags: django, django-templates

In my blog app I want to display a list of blog posts and the first image connected to this post. Now I do it this way:

```
{% for image in entry.image_set.all|slice:"1" %}
    <img src="{{ image.get_absolute_url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a template shortcut I don't know about, or maybe I should just write my own Manager?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Not any shorter, but you could use [`first`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#first):

```
{% with entry.image_set.all|first as image %}
  <img src="{{ image.get_absolute_url }}">
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's slightly cleaner and "feels" better. Is there any difference computationally?

Comment: @voypyg - I'd check that it doesn't actually fetch everything from the database - take a look at the SQL executed.

Comment: It looks as both filters activate the SQL LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 15):

Since Django 1.6 you can do

```
<img src="{{ entry.image_set.first.get_absolute_url }}">
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the following queryset I just want to retrieve first element from it in jinja template.

```
<QuerySet [<StudentDetails: StudentDetails object (1)>, <StudentDetails: StudentDetails object (2)>]>
```

Solution

```
{{ StudentDetails.first.name }}
```

StudentDetails is my model

Answer (score 2):

You also can do:
`entry.image_set.all.0` in your template.