# How to only get first object in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following code, where I get all problem notes.

```
{% for n in task.task_notes.all %}
    {% if n.is_problem %}
        <li>{{ n }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How would I **only** get the first problem note? Is there a way to do that in the template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520554/get-first-item-of-queryset-in-template?rq=1

Comment: Not really -- I'm only getting the first item that has `is_problem=True`. Not the first one in the for loop.

Comment: You could filter in your view (ie `task=Task.objects.filter(is_problem=True)`, I'm guessing), and then use Peter's suggestion

Comment: Yeah, that's the better place to do filtering - more efficient.  Or add a method on `task` that returns the filtered `qs` and use `|first`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need all of the tasks in the template somewhere else.

You can make a reusable [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) (take a look at `first` filter [implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L497) btw):

```
@register.filter(is_safe=False)
def first_problem(value):
    return next(x for x in value if x.is_problem)
```

Then, use it in the template this way:

```
{% with task.task_notes.all|first_problem as problem %}
    <li>{{ problem }}</li>
{% endwith %}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

In the view:

```
context["problem_tasks"] = Task.objects.filter(is_problem=True)
# render template with the context
```

In the template:

```
{{ problem_tasks|first }}
```

`first` template filter [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#first).

---

Would be even better, if you dont need the other problem tasks at all (from 2nd to last):

```
context["first_problem_task"] = Task.objects.filter(is_problem=True)[0]
# render template with the context
```

Template:

```
{{ first_problem_task }}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in the loop:

```
{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}{{ n }}{% endif %}
```