# Get first object of query-set in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I understand that Django separates data and presentation such that `Object.filter(id=value).all()` isn't possible through templates.

What I'm struggling to understand is the best practice for achieving this same type of end result.

For example, in one of my apps I've data for products, which include some one-to-many relationships with images. That's to say, one product may have many images.

in my `AppName/views.py` file, I've got the following:

```
def index(request):

    response = render_to_response('AppName/index.html', context={
        'products': Product.objects.all(),
    })
    return response
```

in my `AppName/templates/AppName/index.html` file, there's a section with the following:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <li>{{ product.name }}: ${{ product.price }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is include the equivalent of `{{product.images.first().url}}` in the mix.

What's the typical approach for this?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520632/214892

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I think that entire _section_ of the documentation is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several options, [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520554/get-first-item-of-queryset-in-template/3520632):

1-(an older approach):

```
{% with entry.image_set.all|first as image %}
  <img src="{{ image.get_absolute_url }}">
{% endwith %}
```

2-Since Django 1.6ish

```
<img src="{{ entry.image_set.first.get_absolute_url }}">
```